# deselect event not working kendo multi-select with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, events, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect, deselect

I am trying to implement deselect event Kendo multi-select component.

This is HTML

```
<div id="multiselect">
    <h4>{{vm.filterGroup.groupName}}</h4>
    <select kendo-multi-select
                    k-data-source="vm.filterGroup.groupItems"
                    k-select="vm.onSelect"
                    k-deselect="vm.onDeselect"
                    k-change="vm.onChange"
                    style="width: 100%"></select>
</div>
```

And this is my deselect method inside the controller

```
vm.onDeselect = function (e: any) {
    console.log('something deselected');            
};
```

Any how when I deselect an item deselect event is not fired. All other select and change events worked fine. Any one knows wht's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have been using previous version of script. 
use below version

2016.3.1118 kendo.all.min.js

It will surely work.

Regards,
Paras

Comment: u mean newest version has an issue? where older one is fine?

Comment: I was using 2016.2.504 version. And it was not supporting desecting event. Finally tried 2016.3.1118 kendo.all.min.js and it started working.

Comment: Ok, since there is no other work around I am accepting your answer. :))